# How to recover my var folder in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

My Ubuntu os was corrupted how can I recover or move my var folder data in another place or usb disk

Any body please help me.

my most important datas are there in var folder

Comment: Is it still accessible with terminal?

Comment: No.os not go to my login page

Comment: Just do one thing, create a bootable live usb of Ubuntu and then you can enter into Ubuntu using that live usb, get the var folder copied to usb and tada

Comment: Ok I will try and inform

Comment: Should we migrate this question to [Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com)?

Comment: @jkdev I feel like we should!

Comment: Ok migrate this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bootable live usb of Ubuntu. Even if you can't access the Ubuntu that you have, login to the Ubuntu which is in this usb, then you can see the drives that your previous Ubuntu was using. Copy the folder you need to usb and now you have the contents you needed!

Comment: Glad I could help!